# Custom colour for bubbles in bubble charts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following sample data:

```
library(ggplot2)

count <- c(100,150,112)
cat <- c("A", "B", "C")
sentiment <- c(-0.3, 0.2, 0.8)
duration <- c(5.6, 8.2,5.2)
silence <- c(0.2, 0.05,0.1)

df <- data.frame(count, cat, sentiment, duration, silence)
```

And I use that data to create the following bubble chart

```
p6 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = duration, y = silence, size = count, colour = sentiment)) + geom_point()
p7 <- p6 + scale_size_continuous(range = c(5, 8))
p7 + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(2, 10)) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,0.25)) + theme(legend.position="none")
```

This all works fine but the thing is that I would like to colour points ranging from green (sentiment = 1) to red(sentiment = -1).

Any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: `scale_color_gradient2(low="Red",high="Green")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `scale_color_continuous` with *low* and *high* as *red* and *green* respectively:

```
+ scale_color_continuous(low = "red", high = "green")
```

gives:

[image]